# i have a register page in react native + redux, i want to include @gmail.com to the email address field

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, redux

i want the user to only enter his starting of the email and the second part that is `@gmail.com`. i want it to be included by its own.
i have tried this email: `''+@gmail.com` but it does not work. it displays `@gmail.com` in the text field that should not be displayed

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
    email: ''+"@gmail.com",
});

<View style={styles.textInputContainerStyle}>
            <Icon
                name='envelope-o'
                type='font-awesome'
                color={colors.BLACK}
                size={18}
                containerStyle={styles.iconContainer}
            />
            <Input
                editable={true}
                underlineColorAndroid={colors.TRANSPARENT}
                placeholder={language.email_placeholder}
                placeholderTextColor={colors.BLACK}
                
                keyboardType={'email-address'}
                inputStyle={styles.inputTextStyle}
                onChangeText={(text) => { setState({ ...state, email: text }) }}
                inputContainerStyle={styles.inputContainerStyle}
                containerStyle={styles.textInputStyle}
            />
        </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to add '@gmail.com' as a TextView component next to the Input component(right), that way the state will contain only the data we need from the user.